# How to inform pathfinding of solid objects blocking path?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, path-finding, tiles

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the thread. Let me know if you can locate the duplicate.

So, I have a my level is an array of tiles, where a tile can either be solid or walkable. I then use A-star to path-find my enemies from one location of the floor to another.

The issue is that I *also* have solid entities. As an example, I may spawn 3 breakable vases at a certain location. They can be larger or smaller than a single tile, and they are just objects in the world, not tiles themselves.

Because they are not a part of the A-star grid (can they? they're larger or smaller than a tile, and their position is not locked to the grid), the path-finding is not aware of their existence, since it only operates on its grid. As a result, sometimes the chosen path for the enemy to follow flows through the solid vases, so the enemy just gets stuck at that location.

Is there a solution that alleviates this problem? I want the enemies to path around the vases (until they're destroyed, of course), instead of just getting stuck trying to unsuccessfully move through them.

Comment: You might want to search for keywords like "navmesh obstacle" or "navmesh cut" for common strategies to address this problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some keywords, so now I know kind of what to look for. Do you have any resources or links on integrating this sort of thing with A-star? Example algorithms? If you put up a short answer of such I'll accept it.

Comment: A* searches a graph - if the graph to reflect things that block a path, then the algorithm will account for them - in general, it doesn't matter if those things are tiles or or not (though on some specific frameworks / implementations it may; if you're using one you should include that info in your question). Regarding changes, in some cases simply re-running A* on an updated graph is sufficient to account for changes.